# i got line from html file using grep in unix script, but i can't figure out how to extract text using sed

Tags: html, unix, sed, grep

i'm making a shell script that shows title and an artist of a song that is played on the radio. i got html file and i found the line that i needed, using grep, but can't figure out how to extract the text that i need.
the line that i got is

```
<div class="n Title">title, different every time </div><div class=n Artist">artist that changes also</div>
```

how do i extract the title and the artist using unix commands?
i have tried many ways but it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po 'Title">\K[^<]*'
```

gives you title, same idea you can get the Artist.  but keep in mind, using regex to "parse" xml/html is risky, for example, the website change the html source, make this in separated lines... or they add some other attributes, or add some other css classes after `Title`...

Comment: Thank you a lot, it's for my homework, when i'll get further with my studies, i'll work on it :)